# merging 2 dataframes and saving taking inputs for all files in a directory

Tags: python, pandas

i have 2 directories, containing this files.

```
Dir1                      Dir2
abc_complete.xlsx    abc_before.xlsx
file2_complete.xlsx    file2_before.xlsx
xyz_complete.xlsx    xyz_before.xlsx
pqr_complete.xlsx    pqr_before.xlsx
```

for `abc_complete.xlsx` i brought it into pandas dataframe (df1)

it contains columns:

```
id   name    sex
1    jon      m
2    sam      m
3    elle     f
4    bob      m
```

for `abc_before.xlsx`pandas df would be (df2):

```
new_sex
    f
    f
    f 
    f
```

I had to delete `'sex'` from `df1` and merge the `'new_sex'` from `df2` into `df1`

My approach:

```
 df1 = pd.read_excel('path/to/file1_complete.xlsx')
 df2 = pd.read_excel('path/to/file1_before.xlsx')
 df1.drop('sex', axis=1, inplace=True)       #dropping column 'sex' from df1
 df1['sex'] = df2['new_sex']                 #joining new sex column from df2
 df1.to_excel('path/to/file1_new.xlsx')
```

this is working fine, but i wanted an automated process, which would take files from my `Dir1 and Dir2`. 
that too in order   `file2_complete.xlsx    file2_before.xlsx` at a time and `xyz_complete.xlsx    xyz_before.xlsx` and so on.

and save the new dataframe with respective file names, abc_new.xlsx,file2_new.xlsx and so on.

is there any way to achieve this automation?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach:

```
import glob
import os

complete_dir = r'C:\Temp\.data\Dir1'
before_dir = r'C:\Temp\.data\Dir2'
# result dir
new_dir = r'C:\Temp\.data\Dir3'

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(complete_dir, '*.xlsx'))


def process_file(fn, complete='_complete', before='_before', new='_new'):
    fn2 = os.path.join(before_dir, os.path.basename(fn.replace(complete,before)))
    new = os.path.join(new_dir, os.path.basename(fn.replace(complete,new)))
    print('processing [{}] ...'.format(fn))
    pd.read_excel(fn, usecols=['id','name']) \
      .assign(new_sex=pd.read_excel(fn2, usecols=['new_sex'], squeeze=True)) \
      .to_excel(new, index=False)

[process_file(f) for f in files]
```

Comment: too complex, i wast thinking of getting all the files in a list and using for loop